# What are the clear differences between autorun and reaction and when to use which?

Tags: javascript, mobx

What is the difference between `autorun` and `reaction`? I'm looking for a full explanation that helps to decide when to use which. Is it possible that `reaction` can even trigger while `autorun` does not? How they are related to each other?

Are these both the same?

```js
autorun(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("current_order", JSON.stringify(this.currentOrder)) 
})
```

```js
reaction(
  () => JSON.stringify(this.currentOrder),
  (json) => { 
    localStorage.setItem("current_order", json) 
  }
)
```

As far as I know, the first parameter of `reaction` will evaluate and check for changes, so it is desired for computed values, but shouldn't `autorun` just work fine if `this.currentOrder` is observable? Will `JSON.stringify(this.currentOrder)` in `reaction` run, even when `this.currentOrder` is observable and has not changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`autorun` runs immediately after it was initialised, `reaction` runs only after the data expression has changed after initialisation.

Also, because `reaction` runs only when data expression changes you can use other observables in the effect function, which would not work for `autorun` because it subscribes for all observables you use inside of it, which means `reaction` gives more fine grained control.

EDIT:

Adding an example to make it more clear

Consider this example, you have two observables A and B, and want to do something with B when A changes, but don't want to do anything when B changes. If you just make `autorun` it will run when any of the observables changes, so it's not what you want. But with `reaction` it's possible to only react to the changes of A (by only using A in expression function).

Comment: The first bit of your answer is useful, but I think the 2nd bit has a flaw. As far as I am aware, observable fields will be converted to proxies on initialization, so their access on the initial run of `autorun` will be registered, so the framework knows which `autorun` functions need to be called when a particular observable field or property changes. That is what I understand when reading the [docs](https://mobx.js.org/understanding-reactivity.html): “MobX reacts to any existing observable property that is read during the execution of a tracked function.”.

Comment: I read further: “"tracked functions" are the expression of `computed`, the rendering of an `observer` React function component, the `render()` method of an `observer` based React class component, and the functions that are passed as the first param to `autorun`, `reaction` and `when`.” So I come to the conclusion that `reaction` should be the right choice, since it has won't need an initial run and can be considered a side-effect.

Comment: Flaw in what way? Maybe I was not clear enough, but consider this example, you have two observables A and B, and want to do something with B when A changes, but don't want to do anything when B changes. If you just make `autorun` it will run when any of the observables changes, so it's not what you want. But with `reaction` it's possible to only react to the changes of A. This is the difference.

Comment: Sorry, there is indeed no flaw, you are right, I misunderstood your answer, your reply is correct. As you stated, `autorun` will trigger when any field inside it changes, "because it subscribes for all observables you use inside of it". Thanks a lot!